# Who can I ask for help to edit a question put on hold?

Tags: support

One of my questions has been put on hold as primarily opinion based and I want rephrase it to meet adequate criteria. Before publishing the edited version, I would like to submit it to more experienced user to get its suggestions. Is it practicable ? How ?

Comment: I recommend you simply make the update and see what people think of it.  If it still seems off-topic people can recommend additional changes.  This is not a "last chance" situation so I don't think you need to worry if your changes are "good enough."

Comment: I will do this way ! Thanks !!